# What's a Sun Ultra 20 motherboard code "44"?

Tags: motherboard

The machine powers on, but the fans don't throttle back, no video, no beep codes.  Motherboard LED is indicating "44", which according to my documentation is a "Reserved" code...

No burst caps in sight, swapped power supplies, no change.  Currently working my way through RAM and peripherals, but knowing what that code actually means would help a ton!